# Match text from beautifulsoup children in Python bs4

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

In the below code I have Beautiful soup data "table":

This is table.prettify

```
<bound method Tag.prettify of <table border="0" cellpadding="14" cellspacing="0"
```

```
rows = table.findChildren(['tr'])
```

These are elements of rows:

```
<tr><td style="width: 166.35pt; padding: 10.5pt;" width="222"><p class="MsoNormal" style="text-justify: inter-ideograph; text-align: justify;"
```

i want to get something like:

```
a1 = 'a1': l1'
a2 = 'a2: r2'
```

Can someone help me in how to cleanly go from "table" to get "a1" and "a2"? Any suggestions are welcome I can probably remove findchildren also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Search for a string using the `text` parameter.
2. Search for the next tag using `find_next()`, which returns the first match.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(your_html, 'html.parser')

a1 = soup.find(text=lambda t: "3" in t)
a2 = soup.find(text=lambda t: "4" in t)

print(a1, a1.find_next(text=True))
print(a2, a2.find_next(text=True))
```

Output:

```
3. Maturity Date: January 12, 2021
4. Offering Amount: About 7,550 billion yen
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
p_tags = rows.find_all('p')

text_lst = []
for index,p in enumerate(p_tags):
    if 'Offering Amount:' in p.text or 'Maturity Date:' in p.text:
        txt = p.text + p_tags[index+1].text
        text_lst.append(txt)

a1 = text_lst[0]
a2 = text_lst[1]

print(a1)
print(a2)
```

Output:

```
3. Maturity Date:January 12, 2021
4. Offering Amount:About 7,550 billion yen
```